# Huawei AG Connect multi environment project with single app

Tags: android, appgallery-connect

I have a project on Huawei App Gallery Connect with one application linked to it. When using FireBase I know you can have different projects to manage the different environments for your app. You can just add the `google-services.json` file in the different buildType directories and the Google Services Plugin does the rest.

I want to do the same with AG Connect so that I can have different Remote Config values in our Staging environment than in our Release environment. Is this possible? I noticed I can't create another project using the same package name (applicationId) and adding another application to the same project doesn't allow me to have different Remote config values.